# Sobre orientar à respeito das políticas do site no quesito "opinião pessoal"

Tags: debate

Como no site não são permitidas perguntas do tipo de boas práticas com opiniões dos desenvolvedores mais experientes, logo indicar sobre este fato e informar que a pessoa terá que ver em outro site caso persista para este tipo de pergunta seria uma boa prática de orientação?

OBS:
Me corrijam caso errei em relação à alguma informação.

Comment: O stackoverflow não é um fórum é um site de Q&A.

Comment: Obrigado pela correção.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Sobre boas práticas e opinião

Antes de mais nada, preciso esclarecer que perguntas que incluem boas práticas são *muito* bem-vindas!

Temos várias perguntas sobre boas práticas, porém, o que geralmente acontece, é que elas são mal formuladas e precisam passam por revisão para serem mais diretas e objetivas de modo a evitar respostas muito curtas, opinativas e de baixa qualidade.

Na verdade, muitos dos usuários irão negativar perguntas e respostas que reforcem práticas ruins de desenvolvimento de software.

Além disso, em muitas situações há opiniões diferentes e ocorrem "discussões" ou "debates" sobre determinada tecnologia ou padrão. Nesses casos, é comum haver duas respostas com pontos de vista diferentes e complementadores.

## O que queremos evitar no Stack Overflow em Português

Desejamos evitar discussões improdutivas e respostas com opiniões sem embasamento, principalmente. Enfim, existem questões que simplesmente não dá para responder.

Na verdade, quase todas as questões e respostas envolvem uma certa dose de opinião. O que precisamos diferenciar é se essa opinião está bem explicada e possui fundamentos teóricos ou pragmáticos.

Por exemplo, considere as perguntas:

> O que vocês acham do novo editor da Microsoft?
>
> Qual é o melhor: Eclipse ou Netbeans?
>
> Qual linguagem vale mais a pena aprender: Python ou Ruby?

Esse tipo de pergunta simplesmente não tem uma resposta. Muito embora, desenvolvedores adorariam defender apaixonadamente seu ponto de vista e poderia gerar uma infinidade de comentários analisando os inúmeros aspectos de cada.

## O que *queremos*  no Stack Overflow em Português

Queremos boas perguntas, as quais possam ser respondidas de forma objetiva, mesmo que com uma dose de opinião e mesmo que seja possível solucionar o problema de várias formas.

Esta é a forma de obter a "opinião" de vários desenvolvedores experientes:

1. Coloque um problema específico
2. Veja como cada um deles resolve
3. Fique com a melhor solução

## Sobre indicação de outros locais para discussão

Discussões como as exemplificadas acima podem ser feitas numa [sala de bate-papo do SOpt](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha), por exemplo.

Em outros casos, acho que não faria mal apontar um local mais adequado para discussão. Por exemplo, alguém fizer uma pergunta sobre um *bug* no Windows, seria interessante indicar num comentário um fórum oficial da Microsoft onde fosse mais adequado postar aquele tipo de pergunta.

No caso de uma discussão sobre alguma linguagem de programação, também não faria mal indicar a lista ou fórum oficial daquela linguagem.

O que não vai pegar bem são "propagandas" de outros fóruns ou a tentativa de usar outro site como uma extensão do SOpt.

Comment: @utuiz, se o fosse: `Qual linguagem vale mais a pena aprender para desenvolvimento de sistemas web onde o sistema terá em torno de 10K usuarios e deverá ter hot swap de componentes: Python ou Ruby?`

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Dá pra responder isso de forma objetiva sem entrar em achismo?

Comment: poderia ser respondida com base em experiencias, quais foram os principais obstáculos que tiveram com a linguagem, quais foram os gargalos, quanto tiveram que aprender, se funcionou satisfatoriamente, eu acho que ter uma resposta mesmo que com base somente em experiencias ou até mesmo em achismo vale mais do que resposta alguma.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Não estou dizendo que a pergunta é ruim,  mas ainda assim ela não engloba qualquer fator determinante para decidir sobre tecnologia. As duas resolvem o problema, então vários usuários podem responder cada um com sua própria experiência e no fim não daria pra saber qual vale mais a pena e nem qual a resposta correta. Me parece que a melhor resposta poderia falar sobre a arquitetura duas tecnologias e sobre as vantagens e desvantagens de cada solução. Mas aí seria melhor fazer a pergunta de forma diferente. E cada linguagem pode ainda ter várias soluções. Complicado!

Comment: @utluiz, Obrigado pelo esclarecimento