# Diferença entre pedido de simples opinião e de recomendação de boas práticas

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, escopo-do-site

Ontem votei pela reabertura [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60729/quais-seriam-as-pr%C3%A1ticas-recomendadas-para-commits-no-git), mas para isso [a editei primeiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/9404), praticamente retornando a edição original do AP (todas as edições [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/60729/revisions)).

Embora tenha me parecido algo impreciso no momento, pois não tinha a opção que procurei, de reverter a edição (acho que por eu não ter rep suficiente), o sistema permitiu esta modificação, e pensei que já que podia editar, então não haveria problema em colocar o conteúdo que entendia apropriado, no caso a pergunta original, que era esta:

> Gostaria de saber, pela experiência de outros programadores, quais seriam, ou as mais usadas práticas de realizar comentários nos commits, para uma melhor comunicação e entendimento.

Talvez não esteja numa redação ideal (o que ficou depois, com a edição do @utluiz), mas mesmo com esta redação acredito que já era possível perceber que se tratava de uma pergunta sobre **boas práticas**, o que está dentro do escopo do site.

*Emenda pior que o soneto* (na verdade não achei a pergunta original ruim, apenas não foi o ideal, como ficou depois), a edição do AP ficou assim:

> Gostaria de saber, se existe algum tutorial, site, blog ou matéria instruindo sobre boas práticas de comentários, em projetos gerenciados com Git, para manter a boa comunicação e entendimento do projeto.

Já neste caso acho que a pergunta ficou realmente ruim, pois o pedido puro e simples (desassociado de um problema específico) de um tutorial/site/blog realmente é algo que não faz muito sentido (talvez se for pra transformar numa lista, ou numa tagwiki, mas este é outro assunto...).

Mas vejamos como ficou a pergunta após a edição do @utluiz:

> Existem práticas recomendadas para realizar *commits* e escrever comentários nesses *commits*, para uma melhor comunicação e entendimento durante o processo de desenvolvimento de software.

Apesar de eu achar que ficou melhor, não alterou substancialmente o sentido da pergunta, a intenção continuou a mesma. Então não acho que o fechamento, neste caso, tenha sido uma boa decisão.

E agora vejam a qualidade [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61425/23400) e [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61431/23400) resposta. Não é uma simples questão de opinião, do tipo "gosto de colocar os comentários assim porque fica mais bonitinho", e sim porque, por exemplo:

> Como já respondi aqui, a principal boa prática é tentar comitar uma
>   funcionalidade por vez, independente se alterou um ou 10 arquivos.
>   Dessa forma seria possível reverter uma mudança em caso de problemas,
>   o que não é tão raro quanto se pensa.

Meu ponto é que não precisa "sair correndo" pra fechar perguntas que se imagina serem de pura e simples opinião, porque elas podem não ser (neste sentido, vide as respostas mais aceitas para as perguntas na lista relacionada ao final).

## A pergunta

Existem vários tópicos discutindo este assunto, e relacionei alguns ao final, então não quero aqui discutir, em tese, se devem ser aceitas questões de recomendação ou de boas-práticas, pois já existem várias perguntas que geraram respostas excelentes tratando deste assunto.

Minha pergunta é específica:

> [Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60729/quais-seriam-as-pr%C3%A1ticas-recomendadas-para-commits-no-git) é de simples opinião ou de recomendação de boas-práticas. Ela está dentro do escopo do SOpt?

Perguntas relacionadas:

- [Devemos aceitar questões de recomendação?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/devemos-aceitar-quest%C3%B5es-de-recomenda%C3%A7%C3%A3o)
- [Como podemos lidar com as listas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/819/como-podemos-lidar-com-as-listas)
- [Onde podemos fazer perguntas, através do SO, que possam ser
  relacionadas a opinião particular de cada um ou envolver links de
  indicação?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144/onde-podemos-fazer-perguntas-atrav%C3%A9s-do-so-que-possam-ser-relacionadas-a-opini)

Mais um tópico relacionado, este recente, e com uma [ótima reposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2729/23400):

- [Sobre orientar à respeito das políticas do site no quesito “opinião
  pessoal”](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2728/sobre-orientar-%C3%A0-respeito-das-pol%C3%ADticas-do-site-no-quesito-opini%C3%A3o-pessoal)

Comment: Achou o momento certo para usar a formatação `[tag:]` né? :) Só há um porém, você pode colocar qualquer coisa depois do `tag:` que ele vai linkar para `http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qualquer-coisa`, o que torna sua afirmação "E existe até uma tagwiki relacionada aqui no SOpt" incorreta, pois como você pode ver no link, exitem 0 perguntas com essa tag.

Comment: Diga-se de passagem, eu já criei uma pergunta com essa tag uma vez, o que levou a criação desse tópico: [Devemos remover meta tags?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/808/3117) Depois disso eu ainda vi essa tag tentar ressurgir das cinzas algumas vezes, mas os usuários de plantão sempre se encarregaram de removê-la.

Comment: @Math pelo jeito ainda não, mas você percebe que estou tentando hard! :-) Eu já tinha visto esta tag em algumas perguntas, então achei que estava ativa. Vou remover este argumento. Valeu!

Comment: @gustavox Concordo plenamente com você, e obrigado por acompanhar esta pergunta. Gostei de suas observações e vou ver os links que foram recomendados. 

 Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Subjetividade boa

Grande parte da prática da Ciência da Computação e da Engenharia de Software, incluindo processos de desenvolvimento, linguagens, tecnologias e até implementação de algoritmo envolve opinião e boas práticas em algum grau.

Entretanto, existe uma clara diferença entre perguntas e resposta com uma [boa ou má subjetividade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/227) e que usam de opiniões da forma apropriada ou não. A principal diferença é que boas opiniões são fundamentadas em bases teóricas ou em experiência pessoal ou de terceiros validadas e reconhecidas pela comunidade de desenvolvimento. Outro fator de uma boa opinião é reconhecer limitações e desvantagens de uma determinada abordagem em relação às outras, além das circunstâncias em que aquilo vale ou não.

No caso da pergunta em questão, sobre Git, commits e comentários, creio tratar-se de uma boa subjetividade, pois embora existam várias formas de se trabalhar e vários profissionais efetivamente trabalham de formas diferentes, existem claramente recomendações oficiais (ou quase), além de práticas que são comuns e consistentes a um conjunto considerável de empresas e desenvolvedores.

Enfim, existe margem para opiniões divergentes, onde cada uma pode analisar a questão de um ponto de vista diferente, mas são visões complementares e que agregam conhecimento sobre a prática do desenvolvimento de software.

## Edições sem mudar o conteúdo

Sobre as edições que fiz na pergunta, minha intenção é realmente não alterar o teor da questão de forma alguma, apenas torná-la mais clara e consistente para os leitores.

Algo que já notei algumas vezes aqui (e faz parte da natureza do ser humano), é que certas palavras "mágicas" disparam gatilhos nas pessoas.

Por exemplo, se a pergunta contém algum trecho como "na opinião" ou "o que vocês acham", as chances da pergunta ser fechada como "baseada em opiniões" aumenta muito.

Além disso, perguntas sem pontuação, formatação e com muitos erros são difíceis de ler. Já vi alguns casos em que tive que fazer um trabalho de interpretação e pesquisa para entender o que o usuário queria. Perguntas assim tendem a ser fechadas como "não está claro o que você está perguntando".

Alguns casos são realmente por "preguiça mental" de alguns usuários, outros são com bom motivo. Por um lado, muitos usuários aqui do SOpt e a moderação lutam para ser amigáveis e se esforçam para "salvar" questões do fechamento. Por outro lado, saber comunicar-se adequadamente é de responsabilidade de todos e obviamente aqueles que sabem fazê-lo melhor obtém mais respostas, votos e benefícios em toda a vida.

Comment: Mas também temos de ver que a pergunta como estava pedia mesmo era opiniões, se ficasse aberta como estava iria gerar um monte de respostas más. A sua edição fez um milagre. Infelizmente a maioria de nós não tem grande jeito para por essas perguntas boas.

Comment: @JorgeB. É verdade que a forma como se pergunta faz toda a diferença. Acho que, infelizmente, só é possível saber a pergunta correta após saber mais ou menos qual é a resposta que se procura. É um problema mais filosófico do que técnico, motivo pelo qual só consigo reformular bem as perguntas para as quais entendo do assunto.

Comment: @utluiz E é por isso que a participação de mais gente editando é tão importante. Pra que a gama de conhecimento dos editores seja ampla o suficiente para saber como resgatar perguntas que apresentam problemas.